# How do I find points within a polygon that are close to the edge of the polygon, using Spatial SQL?

Tags: sql, mariadb, spatial

I have a database of points, and a large polygon which contains all the points. What I want to do is find the points that are close to the edge of the polygon.

The real world application of this is a database of holiday rental cottages, and a multipolygon representing the outline of Great Britain, and I want to be able to add a "close to the coast" flag on all those which are within a few miles of the coast.

Finding points within a polygon is simple enough (ST_WITHIN or ST_INTERSECTS), as is finding points outside the polygon that are nonetheless close to it (ST_DISTANCE). But the distance from a point to a containing polygon is always 0, so ST_DISTANCE is no help here.

I'm using MariaDB as the main dbm, but I can put this into Postgis if that's got relevant features which MariaDB lacks. I'd rather not, though, as the main db will still be MariaDB and I'd prefer to be able to generate this information on the fly from the already-loaded data rather than copying it out to a separate db just for the sake of this calculation.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Deconstruct the polygon to lines, then make a buffer of your desired distance and find intersections of your cottage's points to this buffered lines. In PostGIS is possible in MariaDB I'm not certain. Add dummy sample data so community is able to help.

Comment: Splitting the polygons into lines was an option I'd thought of, because then of course ST_DISTANCE will do precisely what I need. I was just hoping to avoid that if I can. But maybe I'm just trying to be too clever here.

Comment: In PostGIS you could use https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ExteriorRing.html to get a line string of your polygon perimeter.

Comment: Nice! That's available in MariaDB as well, so I can use something like this:

`ST_Distance(location.POINT,ST_ExteriorRing(coast.POLYGON))`

to find locations close to the ring.